# Typescript creating a type with keys based on union type

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

I have a translation object that can have keys corresponding to all of the languages a string might be translated in and the values being the translated strings, like so:

```
const trans = {
  en: "Hello, how is it going?",
  de: "Hallo, wie gehts?",
  da: "Hej, hvordan går det?"
}
```

I am currently typing the object like so:

```
type TransType = {
  [key: string]: string;
}
```

But I also have a union type used in other places to control what languages can be implemented:

```
type Languages = "en" | "de" | "da";
```

How can I bring these two together and control what keys can be used in the trans object based on the Languages union type?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a mapped type for this ([docs](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html)):

```
type Languages = "en" | "de" | "da"

type TransType = {
  [key in Languages]: string
}
// infers TransType = { en: string, de: string, da: string }

const trans: TransType = {
  en: "Hello, how is it going?",
  de: "Hallo, wie gehts?",
  da: "Hej, hvordan går det?",
  nl: "Onbekende taal" // Error, as 'nl' is not in Languages
}
```

Or, as rshepp mentioned, you can use the `Record` utility type ([docs](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#recordkeystype), [src](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/blob/7c10135d9dc64fec166599acdcbeac733f40601d/lib/lib.es5.d.ts#L1499)), which will define the same mapped type:

```
type TransType = Record<Languages, string>
```

[TypeScript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=6&ssc=1&pln=7&pc=1#code/C4TwDgpgBAMghgOwOYFc5IgZygXigIggXygB8CATCE8-CufAKEdEigBUAnRTd8aPAG9GUKAG0A1hBBQAlgliJU6LAF0AXFEzBO8pIwC+URgHoTchADMInbFx582QqEU3bdyADRQqbnXu96Pw8kKANmAGMAewRtKB0eTXtYxwEoYVFXAgAJCAAbPKjvAAsogHc5bFlgKCQovQB+fE8RHwhNfGy4AqKoMtloDGLgTCaW0SCciAArEoA3KM56BSQAU8424DHWhDyOgHkEACMIKQQqeLhukjMoAFFOTkXvOGwAcl23yqgEKJr5RTINAYTCGRhAA)

Comment: You could also declare `type TransType = Record<Languages, string>` or use `Record<Languages, string>` and get effectively the same result.

Comment: Excellent! I did look at the docs for mapped types but understood it wrong at could not get it to work but your example cleared it up for me.

Comment: @rshepp Good call, added it to the answer.

Comment: How might I get this to allow me to have an object without all of the types in the union type, but while still ensuring that the keys in the object are all represented in the union type? If I remove "da" from the object above the compiler will tell me to add it again. I would like it to be optional.

Comment: You can use a `?` to make the properties of a mapped type optional: `type TransType = {[key in Languages]?: string}`.